# Compact mapping [DataSnapshot] to some [Message] efficiently

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Code:

```
database.child("\(groupChatId)_I/messages").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        
        
        guard let messagesArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
            completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
            return
        }

        var finalArray = [[String:Any]]()
        for messageIndex in messagesArray {
            finalArray.append(messageIndex.value as? [String : Any] ?? ["" : ""])
        }
        
        let messages: [Message] = finalArray.compactMap({ dictionary in
            guard let messageId = dictionary["message_id"] as? String,
                let message_content = dictionary["message_content"] as? String,
                let senderName = dictionary["sender_name"] as? String,
                let senderEmail = dictionary["sender_email"] as? String,
                let message_type = dictionary["message_type"] as? String
                else { return nil }
            
             ...

            return Message(sender: sender,
                           messageId: messageId,
                           sentDate: Date(),
                           message_content: message_content,
                           kind: finalKind)
        })
        completion(.success(messages))
    })
```

Is there a more efficient way of compact mapping messagesArray from [DataSnapshot] to [Message] more efficiently and without that ugly for loop?

The intention is I need to retrieve an array from my database while also being ordered by childByAutoId(). Is there another way of retrieving the same ordered array without it being in the form of [DataSnapshot] OR some form that is easy to work with/compact map?